# Delete Saved Proxy Credentials in Firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy

I have my proxy credentials saved in a Firefox Portable that I want to share with my friend  but I don't want him to sue my credentials. I've looked around for hours but can't find any way to clear the proxy credentials.

I just want the authentication box to pop up and be empty.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Steve

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself...

Options -> Security -> Saved Passwords DOH!

Steve

Comment: Extremely useful, since my old credentials constantly overwrote the newly ones. Deleting that entry, I have been able to let Firefox memorize the one I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the option is slightly different than Steve's answer:

I found mine in

Options -> Privacy & Security -> Saved Logins (under Logins and Passwords section) -> On the left

The proxy password was prefixed with "moz-proxy" in my saved logins